# Using a mix of authentication schemes in a Blazor Server application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

I have an application that I use Windows Authentication for most of the application and it works wonderfully.  There is an API for handing out tidbits that uses a bearer token instead of Windows Authentication that works fine as well.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RoleAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddNegotiate()
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BearerAuthHandler>("Bearer", null);

[other initializations]

app.UseAuthorization();
```

App.razor

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
```

APIController.cs

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyAPIController : ControllerBase
```

The issue is when accessing the site from non-Windows devices (usually mobile) it does not authenticate correctly.  There is a login dialog presented from the browser, and once authenticated I see the logged in user briefly, but it then changes to the anonymous authentication within a few seconds.

How can I allow the Windows authentication to work for mobile devices while using anonymous authentication for the API?

Comment: When you say "Windows authentication" - are you referring to on-prem (i.e. Active Directory (not Azure AD btw) with Negotiate+Kerberos+NTLM? If so, do you have Active Directory's own SSO (SAML/OIDC) working? If you want mobile-devices to work with your application does that include when those devices connect over the public Internet, or intended to only work in a LAN-only scenario, where those mobile-devices _must_ connect to your on-prem wifi?

Comment: ...but assming you want something that works reliably regardless of how the user is connecting/accessing this application, I recommend disabling "Windows" (Negotiate/Integrated/NTLM) auth and instead using _only_ Windows Server's SSO SAML (or OIDC) auth (this assumes your AD Federation box is publicly accessible over the Internet, ofc) - otherwise you'll have PHBs complaining it doesn't work when their phone fallsback to LTE when in a wifi dead-zone.

Comment: Yes, on-prem AD authentication that I wanted to happen automatically.  This is only used on an internal company network.